# Failure with `builtins` while publishing to NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I have this failure trying to publish a package

`npm ERR! builtins is not a function`

Which comes from

```
37 verbose stack TypeError: builtins is not a function
37 verbose stack     at validate (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/validate-npm-package-name/lib/index.js:55:3)
37 verbose stack     at Result.setName (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:127:17)
37 verbose stack     at new Result (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:119:10)
37 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:56:15)
37 verbose stack     at npa (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:26:18)
37 verbose stack     at Function.pickRegistry (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/lib/index.js:189:10)
37 verbose stack     at Publish.exec (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/lib/commands/publish.js:107:33)
37 verbose stack     at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/typeorm-seeding/typeorm-seeding/node_modules/npm/lib/cli.js:66:5)
```

Does someone have any idea? I could not found any info about this error.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else comes across this, I had the same exact issue (first time using node.js on a Windows machine).  Not much out there that speaks to this problem, so the fix for me was to completely un-install Node - then reinstall it.

Then, this error went away.

Comment: Fresh Installed Node 16.16.0 (LTS), but the error keep showing.
TypeError builtins is not a function at validate ...

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced this problem and was stuck with this for three days.
With me, all my "node" and "npm" were up to date but all the commands with npm apart from the version check ie "npm -v" was giving me more or less the same error "builtins is not a function".

sol 1 - One can try to uninstall node and npm and then re-install from the fresh.

If that doesn't solve the problem and you are still getting the same error then try the next solution

sol 2 - Install yarn https://phoenixnap.com/kb/yarn-windows

Use yarn commands instead of "npm". The following link will help you find all the yarn commands equivalent to npm commands.
https://www.sitepoint.com/yarn-vs-npm/

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33264491)